# ListFragment setListAdapter to custom adapter found outside fragment class

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity with a layout, and the layout consists of a fragment that is a ListFragment. Insise my ListFragment derived class, I want to set the ListFragment from an adapter that is located inside the activity whose layout holds the fragment. Is there a way to pass the adapter to the fragment onActivityCreated, or do I need to create a new adapter inside the onActivityCreated method?

MainActivity.java --> adapter instance is here

activity_main.xml --> fragment is located in this viewgroup

MyListFragment.java --> I want to use setListAdapter(myAdapter) in onActivityCreated

If question doesn't make sense let me know. I am new to android and might have to reword.

Comment: Question makes sens ... but touching UI which not belongs to Fragment not (with exclusion of menus of course) ... let `Activity` implements `IProvideMeAnAdapter` interface ...

Answer (score 0):

Create one public method in activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    public YourAdapter getYourAdapter(){
    return adapterInstatnce;
    }
}
```

In your ListFragment :

in `onActivityCreate()`

```
final YourAdapter yourAdapter = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getYourAdapter();
```

Comment: other option is you can create interface for it also.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass just the adapter "data" from activity to fragment (use `newInstance` method), and the create the adapter inside the fragment.